# How do I tell Chrome to (once again) default to HTTPS for a site?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I visit an old MediaWiki-based site; let's call it `wiki.example.com`.  For the longest time I would type "wiki." into the URL bar, and Chrome would autocomplete it to `https://wiki.example.com`.  The same would be true if I auto-completed other URLs for pages on that site.

However recently, for no reason I can tell, Chrome has started autocompleting it with the insecure `http://` version of the site.  How can I make Chrome assume that this site should always use HTTPS ... as it used to?

Also, if you happen to know *why* this happened I'm curious, but it's not important if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try this Addon [HTTPS Everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?date=2006-07-24)

edited;
If you want specific site auto complete. Then bookmark it, when you are typing the site address it will complete correctly

Comment: Thanks. That might work, but I was really hoping not to force every site to be `https`, as some sites shouldn't be: I just want to solve the problem with this one specific site (which, again, Chrome *used to* have no trouble with ...)

Comment: Clear history, and bookmark your favorite site

Comment: Tried that, didn't help :(